# How would I change this query to fit into Laravel's Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've tried creating this query in Laravel and still can't get it to work with a query builder. It's giving me syntax errors yet I can run it in the tables and it run smooth.

**Query trying to run:**

```
select A.*, sum(RawAmt) as AmountOwed from (select Login, PatID,
if(length(ApptID) > 0, ApptID, VisitID) as VisitID,
ServiceDate,
TotalCharge,
InsurancePaid,
PrevPaid,
WriteOff,
Refund,
MiscDebit,
AmountOwed as RawAmt,
ApptTime,
ApptDate,
Physician,
isCopay,
HLocation from MDPay_AcctHist where Login='demo') A
group by PatID, VisitID
```

It's giving me a syntax issue when trying to do this with DB::raw statements in DB::select and DB::where;

Any help on trying to write this to meet laravels specs would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subquery = DB::selectRaw('
        Login, PatID,
        if(length(ApptID) > 0, ApptID, VisitID) as VisitID,
        ServiceDate,
        TotalCharge,
        InsurancePaid,
        PrevPaid,
        WriteOff,
        Refund,
        MiscDebit,
        AmountOwed as RawAmt,
        ApptTime,
        ApptDate,
        Physician,
        isCopay,
        HLocation')
    ->from('MDPay_AcctHist')
    ->where('Login', '=', 'demo')
    ->toSql();

$result = DB::selectRaw('A.*, sum(RawAmt) as AmountOwed')
    ->from(DB::raw($subquery . ' as A'))
    ->groupBy('PatID', 'VisitID')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Ok, so I dropped this code in and got this: syntax error, unexpected '}'. I tried ending the where('Login', '=', 'demo') with a ; and I got this: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw'. how do I need to fix this to make it work correctly?

Comment: Yeah, you added the semicolon exactly where I did, look above in my comment and I'm now getting the:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw'.

Comment: yuo, we should replace `selectRaw()` with `select(DB::raw())` here, see updated answer.

Comment: I actually did this and now I'm running into this issue: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'A' (SQL: select A.*, sum(RawAmt) as AmountOwed)

The reason this is happening is because of this end statement not being in the query you created: ... where Login='demo') A
group by PatID, VisitID

How would I get the ) A group by PatID, VisitID in there? That's defining A.* at top.

Comment: good question, I don't know the answer, so I separated it to subquestion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29970481/1331425

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I really do appreciate it. Sometimes corporate queries are a little harder to create in Laravel, and you helping has at least wrapped my mind around how this can work. I'll follow your question and see where it ends up.

Comment: You're welcome! I got the answer on our subquestion and amended this answer, take a look.