# Laravel - named subquery using Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery, query-builder

In [MySQL subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) documentation there's an exmaple of subquery:

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
```

Here's the raw query which I want to transform:

```
select SUBQUERY_NAME.* from (select id, name from items) AS SUBQUERY_NAME
```

Is there any way to do this in Laravel Query Builder without using `DB::raw()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly no. The Query Builder has its limitations and more complex queries are outside its scope, that's why `DB::raw()` is there. But, if you want to make it a little more elegant and generate the subquery using the Query Builder, you could do something like this this:

```php
$subquery = DB::table('items')->select('id', 'name')->toSql();
DB::table(DB::raw($subquery . ' as subquery_name'))->select('subquery_name.*');
```

Comment: You may add brackets to avoid an SQL syntax error `'('.$subquery->toSql().') as subquery_name'`